# Spyder on pc - can't open files

Tags: python

Please help if possible. Hopefully just a quick question.

I'm trying to open txt files and csv files onto spyder using python on a laptop - microsoft pc.

Trying to implement the code below but it wont open anything - I've tried lots of variations
Hope you can help, many thanks.

```
def print_file(filename):
    """ Opens file and prints its contents line by line. """
    infile = open(filename)

    for line in infile:
    print(line, end="")    
    infile.close()
```

print_file("phones.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    print_file("phones.csv")

File "", line 3, in print_file
    infile = open(filename)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'phones.csv'

Also = when I implement !cd it says the operating files are my c drive and the files are in there.

Been trying for several days so hope you don't mind question x

Comment: is `phones.csv` in the same folder as your script?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've taken your advice and copied the code into a new script window -on the left and it's now saved into the same folder as the csv and txt files - my documents. Is that right? Is that what you meant? x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two things wrong here. First, you didn't indent your print function call in the for loop properly. Second, you aren't giving the correct filename to the function.

Here is an example of how this can work:

correct function:

```
def print_file(filename):
    """ Opens file and prints its contents line by line. """
    infile = open(filename)

    print("Opened file, now printing it...")
    for line in infile:
        print(line, end="")
    infile.close()
```

I have a csv file `phones.csv` on my Desktop, so I call it like this:

```
dir = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/'
filename = 'phones.csv'
print_file(dir + filename)
```

Output:

```
Opened file, now printing it...
123 456 1243, 423 653 6543, 234 532 5432, 543 873 6433, 975 523 5235,
453 856 5435, 423 575 5623, 742 423 9432, 523 634 8345, 421 724 5432
```

and the contents of `phones.csv` is

```
123 456 1243, 423 653 6543, 234 532 5432, 543 873 6433, 975 523 5235,
453 856 5435, 423 575 5623, 742 423 9432, 523 634 8345, 421 724 5432
```

Comment: Also, if the script is in the same folder as your .csv, you do not need the function call with `dir`